# I wanna make a textbox that can collect the answer and bind with search url

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a textbox that can collect the answer and bind it with the search url.

My problems are that I can type in the text box, but it won't the script.

The error being displayed is:

> Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById is not a constructor
>
> at myFunction (index.html:23)
>
> at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:14)

Tested in Chrome and Maxthon 5

And Here is my Code
https://hastebin.com/uqelimudoc.xml

Comment: Why are you using `new` on that line?

Comment: Remove `new` from `var z = new document.getElementById("version").innerHTML;` line.

Comment: what do you mean by z < 035?Can you explain in detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `new` when you're trying to access `document`.

Also a suggestion would be to use generic word for `input` `name` rather than a URL.

Working code snippet

```
<form id="myForm" method="get">
  Version: <input type="text" name="http://dtht-webfile.000webhostapp.com/SS/#search=" placeholder="Example:0.3.1"><br>
</form>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Search</button>

<p id="version"></p>
<p></p>
<p id="final"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
    document.getElementById("version").innerHTML = y;
    // var z = document.getElementById("version").innerHTML;
    // z is same as y

    if (y < 035) {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "You're Lastest Version.";
   } else {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "You're Outdated. Please Go Download Lastest.";
   }
}
</script>
```

If you're expecting a number to be user input then it'd be better to use appropriate input type or use regex to allow only number or else you can do the following before comparing `y` in the above code with `Number(y)`

Working fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/k9d9hwbz/

Comment: Always you will get "You're Lastest Version."Do check once.

Comment: @HameedSyed That is becasue input type is `text` and the comparison is for a `Number` ( `z < 035` ).

Comment: @HameedSyed Updated with jsfiddle link which works fine in case value is less than 35

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt explain with the above comments,so rewriting again only the script function.

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var y = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
    document.getElementById("version").innerHTML = y;
    var z = document.getElementById("version").innerHTML;

    //z will be in the form of string,converting it to number format
    if (Number(z) > 3.5) {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "You're Lastest Version.";
   } else {
    document.getElementById("final").innerHTML = "You're Outdated. Please Go Download Lastest.";
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The value of `z` and `y` is the same. You could avoid unnecessary DOM operation there by using `y` itself for comparison instead of `z`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in line no 23.

```
var z = new document.getElementById("version").innerHTML;
```

Remove the new keyword and execute the code.

Going through the code in line no 21

```
var y = document.getElementById("myForm").elements[0].value;
```

This line works but going further assign unique ID's for elements and get elements using that ID. As the code gets lengthier, ID's will help you a lot.

Use this for reference https://www.w3schools.com/

After getting familiar with JavaScript go through jQuery

working fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sainadhvemula/7yqsgsp9/)